# Changing Body Text in WooCommerce Customer Processing Order Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the body text (the text below the header) within the mail recieved when ordering an item. I have copied the customer-processing-order.php to my child theme, and I have tried to edit the text string, which does nothing. Under ‘Processing Order’ in Woocommerce – Settings – Email I have it set to HTML. From my search online this should do the trick, but somehow doesn't.

When recieving the template it is translated to my native tongue (it is in english within the template) which makes me wonder if it is translated somewhere (I have no translation plugin installed).

I have tried different php solutions offered from other threads and nothing seems to work. Am I copying / editing the wrong file? Or something else?

Here is the code I'm editing:

```
<?php translators ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Testing the  text string Just to let you know &mdash; we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>
```

I hope someone can shed some light on what might be going wrong. From the guides I've found it *should* work, alas it does not :(

Answer (score 0):

did you copy the file to the correct path?

```
child_theme_folder/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php
```

What is it?

```
<?php translators ?>
```

Because if is function, must be

```
<?php translators(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php translators($correct_variable); ?>
```

Comment: I did it from the back end - it was doable from within WooCommerce - Mail, so I guess it must be correct. <?php translators ?> was something that were there from the beginning. I've tried to just remove it, with no luck either

Comment: OK, try copy the file from `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/email` not from your theme folder, because theme probably use some custom modifications.

Comment: Hmm, I found a solution - apparently it was a cache problem. Flushed the WooCommerce Template Cache, and I could start editing. Thanks for the input tho!